# Passing values from one component to another when button is clicked-React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the two component that I want to pass data from  Index component to ViewItem component.

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employeeList: [
        {
          id: "1",
          uname: "Jane",
          email: "jane@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          uname: "Joe",
          email: "joe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          uname: "Rasik",
          email: "rasik@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleViewEmployee = (id) => {
    const list = this.state.employeeList;
    const employee = list.filter((employee) => employee.id == id);
    return employee;
  };

  render() {
    const employeeList = this.state.employeeList;
    return (
      <div>
        <Table striped>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Emp id</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {employeeList.map((employee) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{employee.id}</td>
                <td>{employee.uname}</td>
                <td>{employee.email}</td>
                <td>
                  <Link to="/admin/employee/view">
                    <Button
                      variant="outline-success"
                      onClick={this.handleViewEmployee(employee.id)}
                    >
                      View
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class ViewItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uname: "",
      email: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table style={{ padding: "10px", marginTop: "20px" }}>
          <tbody style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
            <tr>
              <td> Username</td>
              <td>{this.props.uname}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> Email</td>
              <td>{this.props.email}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I clicked on View button on "Index" component it should return array item that match with the employee id. And this item that should get the second component "ItemView" to display it. This way is not working? Is there any other way that I can follow?
Thanks.

Routing:

```
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
render(
<Router>
    <ViewItem path="/admin/employee/view" />
 </Router>)
```

Comment: Is there some routing/navigation involved here? Like `ViewItem` is rendered on a `Route`? Are you just wanting to send the data as part of the route state *during* the navigation PUSH? You can't really have a `Link` ***AND*** a button with an `onClick` handler and expect the link to wait for the click handler to finish and magically receive the return value. They are 100% independent from one another.

Comment: Yes. Routing is there. I want to view single employee details in another page when I click on view button for each employee. I understand. I want a way to pass those data.

Comment: What routing solution is being used? Can you provide what is imported and used? The component with the routes? How `ViewItem` is being rendered?

Comment: I have edited the question with routings.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing a lot of detail to be answered properly but based on your comment I will try to make some assumption to give you some pointer.

**Assumptions:**

1. You use react-router, if you don't the logic will stay the same but I will use react-router for my example
2. On click you want to navigate to a new page with the detail

**What's should be changed:**

1. First and foremost, you have a critical error when you declare your onClick listener. You are calling handleViewEmployee on render instead of referencing it for the onClick listener:

```
<Button
    variant="outline-success"
    onClick={this.handleViewEmployee(employee.id)} // Calls on render
>
    View
</Button>
```

should be

```
<Button
    variant="outline-success"
    onClick={() => this.handleViewEmployee(employee.id)} // Called on click
>
    View
</Button>
```

2. You want to navigate to a new page. Currently, your handleViewEmployee function is only returning your employee and nothing is done with it. Furthermore, you should probably use find instead of filter but that depends on your use case I suppose.
3. You need to [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If you want your two components to access the same data and any of them is the parent of the other, you need to have somewhere a common parent handling this data. Depending on the complexity of your app you have multiple choices: local state, [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or a full fledge state management solution like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) to only cite two. I will use local state in my example  to keep it simple

Once you have all of this you can navigate to your new page and show the details

**Example:**

This example is really basic but I'm sure it can get you on the right track

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      employees: [{
        id: '1',
        uname: 'Jane',
        email: 'jane@gmail.com'
      }, {
        id: '2',
        uname: 'Joe',
        email: 'joe@gmail.com'
      }, {
        id: '3',
        uname: 'Rasik',
        email: 'rasik@gmail.com'
      }]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {employees} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={'/admin/employee/view/:id'} component={() => <ViewItem employees={employees}/>}/>
            <Route path={'/admin/employee'} component={() => <Index employees={employees}/>}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {employees} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Emp id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Action</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          {employees.map((employee) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{employee.id}</td>
              <td>{employee.uname}</td>
              <td>{employee.email}</td>
              <td>
                <Link to={`/admin/employee/view/${employee.id}`}>
                  <button>
                    View
                  </button>
                </Link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ViewItem = ({employees}) => {
  const {id} = useParams();
  const employee = employees.find(el => el.id === id);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <table style={{padding: '10px', marginTop: '20px'}}>
        <tbody style={{padding: '10px'}}>
        <tr>
          <td> Username</td>
          <td>{employee.uname}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Email</td>
          <td>{employee.email}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

PS: Remember to add a key to your element in the map:

```
{employees.map((employee) => (
    <tr key={employee.id}>
        <td>{employee.id}</td>
        <td>{employee.uname}</td>
        <td>{employee.email}</td>
        <td>
            <Link to={`/admin/employee/view/${employee.id}`}>
                <button>
                    View
                </button>
            </Link>
        </td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Comment: This the answer I wanted. Thanks. It solved the problem.

Comment: My pleasure, remember to set the question as answered. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data in route state. Since the `Link` is in the `employeeList.map` callback scope you can simply enclose the current `employee` in the callback in route state.

```
<Link
  to="/admin/employee/view"
  state={{ employee }} // <-- from the array being mapped
>
  <Button variant="outline-success">
    View
  </Button>
</Link>
```

`ViewItem` can access route state from the `location` route prop.

```
this.props.location.state.employee
```

[Link](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link)
[Route Component](https://reach.tech/router/api/RouteComponent)

Comment: It gives this error on ViewItem component. TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: @Dinuka I linked the two relevant documents, `Link` for sending state, and Route component, that receives the state on the passed `location` prop. Are you sure your shared code snippet is accurate?